# UIViewanimation animationDidStop method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have a 8 `imagaviews` that I have added to my view with `size (0,0)`. Now what I want to do is to pull op each imageView after each other with a `UIViewanimation`. I want to do 2 animations. First the size should go to from `(0,0) --> (105,85)` and after that is finished the imageview size should go from  `(105,85) --> (93,75)`

Now I have a method where I first place all my imageViews on the correct place.All the images have `size (0,0)` At the end I call the method `startAnimating`

```
-(void)startAnimating{
    [self animageButton:[arrButtons objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Then the first view animation ( from (0,0) --> (105,85) )

```
-(void)animageButton:(UIImageView *)imgButton{
    loopIndex++;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    CGRect btnFrame = imgButton.frame;
    btnFrame.size.width = 105;
    btnFrame.size.height = 85;
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.5f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                    animations:^{
                        imgButton.frame = btnFrame;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self animageButton2:imgButton];


}
```

this calls the second method (from (105,85) --> (93,75))

```
-(void)animageButton2:(UIImageView *)imgButton{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    CGRect btnFrame2 = imgButton.frame;
    btnFrame2.size.width = 93;
    btnFrame2.size.height = 75;

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.5f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                    animations:^{
                        imgButton.frame = btnFrame2;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Now at this point the first imageView should be animated. Now when the animation has finished. I to this.

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    //do smth
    if(loopIndex <= 7){
         NSLog(@"called");
        UIImageView *imgObj = [arrButtons objectAtIndex:loopIndex];
        [self animageButton:imgObj];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"done");
        return;
    }

}
```

What it is doing at the moment it is animating all the images at the same time. But I want that the next imageview starts animating when the previous has done.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You really really should use the newer way of animation that has been around since iOS 4.0 (`[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion]`).  It has a very simple way of running an animation on completion.

Comment: @borrrden this did the trick. But now the animation starts at the topleft corner. Is their a way to start it in the center of the imageview?

Comment: Look into `CALayer`'s `anchorPoint` property.  If that doesn't help, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)startAnimating
{
    NSTimeInterval delay = 0.0;
    for(UIImageView *imageView in arrButtons)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(animageButton:) withObject:imageView afterDelay:delay];
        delay +=1.0;
    }
}

-(void)animageButton:(UIImageView *)imgButton{

    CGRect btnFrame = imgButton.frame;
    btnFrame.size.width = 105;
    btnFrame.size.height = 85;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        imgButton.frame = btnFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self animageButton2:imgButton];
    }];
}

-(void)animageButton2:(UIImageView *)imgButton
{
    CGRect btnFrame2 = imgButton.frame;
    btnFrame2.size.width = 93;
    btnFrame2.size.height = 75;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        imgButton.frame = btnFrame2;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

I have not tested the code. Let me know if there are any issues. Thanks.